# Adding images to a folder in SDCARD

Tags: android, android-studio

**Everytime the image is captured the folder creation section works fine but the image is not added to the folder**

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}
});
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) 
{
folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator+"folder/");                          

if(!folder.exists())

        {
            folder.mkdirs();
            Log.d("SDcard", "Folder created");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("SDCard", "Folder already exists");
        }
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +        File.separator +"folder/");
        Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);    ` 
        }
        }
```

If I add the folder creation and save image logic to the onclick() directly it shows error stating    "Failure delivering result info"

***Please do help ***

Comment: you do it wrong, if you want to give the intent extra, then add it in your click listener

Comment: @ Randyka Yudhistira can you please elaborate ? Ive declared the cameraIntent object before oncreate() method...So there is no problem with its scope..it shows no errors ! But the image is not added to the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void saveBitmapToFile(Bitmap bmp) {

        File mAppBaseDir;
        if (isExternalStorageWritable())
            mAppBaseDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "FolderName");
        else
            mAppBaseDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParent()).getAbsoluteFile();

        if (!mAppBaseDir.exists()) {
            mAppBaseDir.mkdirs();
        }
        File imageDir = new File(mAppBaseDir, "Profile");
        if (!imageDir.exists())
            imageDir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(imageDir + "/" + "profile.png");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        try {
            writeBytesToFile(file, bitmapToByte(bmp));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // show alert for retry choose photo
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



public void writeBytesToFile(File file, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bos.write(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (bos != null) {
                try {
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

public byte[] bitmapToByte(Bitmap bitmapFinally) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmapFinally.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for responding..But compiler could not resolve Tools class.Is it a user defined class or does it require any imports ?

Comment: Sorry @Gopi, i added bitmapToByte method. yo cou can delete "Tools".
Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question based on your comment *"can you please elaborate"*. CMIIW :

```
photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "folder/");

        if (!folder.exists())

        {
            folder.mkdirs();
            Log.d("SDcard", "Folder created");
        } else {
            Log.d("SDCard", "Folder already exists");
        }
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "folder/");
        Uri photoPath = Uri.fromFile(file);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoPath);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
});
```

*"Ive declared the cameraIntent object before oncreate() method"* 
that's no problem about that, but onActivityResult will be triggered after you call startActivityForResult, then the intent wont have the extra you give

Comment: I've mentioned that this dint work in my question (If I add the folder creation and save image logic to the onclick() directly it shows error stating "Failure delivering result info") logcat shows "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} " and application closes by itself

Comment: result -1? do press back button when camera app open?

Comment: No.I pressed the TICK button only